# how to save hide/show attribute to database?

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, database, show-hide

I'm trying to make a comments section in my website. and the users comments are stored in the database.Below is my database structure:

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| comment  | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| post_id  | int(10)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status   | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created  | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

How can I save in my database that a comment is hidden or shown?

for clarity, here's the scenario and what I want to achieve:

User: inputs comment then submits, comment is then saved. status value is 1 meaning comment is shown.

Admin(decides the comment is inappropriate): hides the comment status value should be 0 meaning the comment is now hidden.

How can I do this? currently all I could do is jquery.hide() and .show(), but then shows when the page is reloaded or refreshed?Any help suggestion is highly appreciated

**Jquery**

```
$(".hide_comment").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
    $('#comment-' + id).hide();
});

$(".show_comment").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
    $('#comment-' + id).show();
});
```

Comment: update the database when user submits comment and when admin changes.why are you using jQuery?

Comment: Please tell me exact requirement. Do you want to hide the comment if comment status is disabled from admin side? If you want to hide the comments if status is disabled then while iterating comments you should check the status whether u can display the comment or not. if you want to change the status from admin side then you have to use jquery ajax to change the comment status. let me know clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For e.g:

Add a new field

```
`is_visible` tinyint(1) not null default 1
```

then generated html using server side script:

```
// PHP Example
foreach($db_results as $each) {
    echo '<div data-comment-id="' . $each->id . '" class="comment-box"' . ($each->is_visible?' style="display: block;"':'') . '>';
    echo $each->comment;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Then for client side script using jQuery:

```
$('.comment-box').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggle();
    // Also you can make an ajax request to server to save visibility status and send id of comment by reading data as:
    console.log($(this).data('comment-id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the table to accept a new column - IsHidden or smth

```
alter table comments add column ishidden bool;
```

And handle the status changes with ajax calls :

```
$(".hide_comment").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log($(this).data('id'));

        var currentData = {
               id : id,
               isHidden: true
             };

        $.ajax({
           url: "some.php",
           data: currentData,
           success: function(response){
                        if(response.itHasBeenSaved){

                          $('#comment-' + id).hide();
                             }
                 }
             });

    });
```

And you can do the same for show. You will try to change the status in database on server (that's why you use an ajax call) and then if the ajax call succeeded you change the status accordingly.